# How to decide the degree of parallelism in a loop body consisting of CPU and I/O bound operations?

Tags: parallel-processing, async-await

I am using a ForEachAsync loop as described in this blog post at [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/).

My loop body executes a combination of I/O (async/await) and CPU bound operations. In such a case, what all factors need to be taken into account for deciding degree of parallelism?

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    int degreeOfParallelism,
    Func<T, Task> body)
{
    if (degreeOfParallelism <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(degreeOfParallelism));
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner
                          .Create(source)
                          .GetPartitions(degreeOfParallelism)
        select Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (partition)
            {
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                {
                    await body(partition.Current);
                }
            }
        }));
}

public async Task ProcessChangesAsync(
    IChangeFeedObserverContext context,
    IReadOnlyList<Document> docs,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // This function receives list of documents that need to be processed in parallel
    await docs.ForEachAsync(8, async doc =>
    {
        await ProcessDocument(doc);
    });
}

public async Task ProcessDocument(Document doc)
{
    // We get other details for this entity from database.
    var dbResult = await repository.GetDetailsFromDB(doc);

    // Get some more data from external services
    var moreDetails = await httpClient.GetMoreDataFromOtherServices(dbResult);

    // The data fetched above consists of list of elements and we iterate over the list and run business logic.
    // Use data mappers to convert the data back to entities. These are all CPU bound operations

    // Then finally we persist details in DB
    await repository.WriteToDB(...);
}
```

Comment: It's an almost 7 years old article. Maybe there are better patterns now. Can you show your code?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to limit the number of running tasks, why not let the system and the work itself work their way?

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> body)
    => Task.WhenAll(from item in source select body(item));
```

Comment: I want to limit the number of tasks as we have many tasks running as part of the service. I wanted to understand if there are any guidelines to follow when we apply parallelism to async calls.

Comment: Why do you want to limit the number of tasks running and based on what criteria?

Comment: Since I have CPU bound computation in my loop. I want to avoid over-parallelism. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism#avoid-over-parallelization)

Comment: But you also have IO, and the task scheduler will, eventually,  throttle the execution of the CPU-bound tasks.

Comment: Sounds right not to limit IO without for sure knowing if the CPU is throttled.